# Retrieve flows for a given maximum bipartite graph matching

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph and we can use FindMaximumFlow to find the maximum amount of pairings in such a graph. But I want to know the actual paths as well, not just the maximum amount of them.

[image]

For instance: In the documentation there is:

[image]

But what good is this to anyone, practically? Surely this HR manager person will actually have to pair up the particular person with a particular job. In other words, he wants a table of the paths not just the amount of them. For a small number like in this example, sure the paths are visible, but for a bigger one, good luck.
Should I just construct my own tailored ford-fulkerson for this or is there something I am missing in FindMaximumFlow?

Thanks in advance. (For site mods: I cannot use either bipartite nor matching as tags due to low reputation, even though those are exactly the words to describe this.)

Comment: Did you have a look at optimumflowdata?

Comment: If you are implying that the optimumflowdata object holds the flows then I do not know how to extract them, again, not sure what I am missing https://puu.sh/IYIFu/f2cb9b120e.png

Comment: `maxPairs["Properties"]` will return a list of available properties, in your case, I think it's `maxPairs["EdgeList"]` that you're looking for. Also have a look at [`FindIndependentEdgeSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentEdgeSet.html) (specially Applications's section).

Comment: it is "EdgeList" actually, my bad I didnt notice it.

Comment: Also you can use `EdgeCount` instead of `Length[EdgeList[...]]`.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed the "EdgeList" property of the optimumFlowData object!
The problem is also I did this in a bad way by introducing a sink and a source (which gives me 3 times the paths) whereas I should've just used the vertexes only as in the documentation examples which made me think "EdgeList" is simply all the edges of the original graph.

```
    Clear[lists, graph, pP, pPi]
pP[x__] := (
  {x}[[1]] -> # & /@ Drop[{x}, 1]
  )
Clear[pPi]
pPi[x__] := (
  # -> Last [{x}] & /@ Drop[{x}, -1]
  )
lists := Join[
  pP[s1, m1, m2, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12, m13, 
   m15, m16, m17, m18, m19, m20, m21, m23, m24, m25, m26], 
  pP[m1, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, 
   f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, f28, 
   f29, f31, f33], 
  pP[m2, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, 
   f15, f16, f17, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, f36, 
   f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m3, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, 
   f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, 
   f36, f37, f28, f20, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m4, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, 
   f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f35, f36, 
   f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m5, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f14, f15, f16, f18, 
   f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, f28, f31, f33], 
  pP[m6, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, 
   f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, 
   f36, f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m7, f1, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, 
   f16, f17, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f24, f25, f26, f34, f35, f36, 
   f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f32], 
  pP[m8, f1, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, 
   f16, f17, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f24, f25, f26, f35, f36, f37, 
   f28, f29, f38, f31, f32], 
  pP[m9, f1, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, 
   f16, f17, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, 
   f28, f29, f38, f31], 
  pP[m10, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f14, f15, f16, f18, 
   f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, f28, f31, f33], 
  pP[m11, f1, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, 
   f16, f17, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f24, f25, f26, f34, f35, f36, 
   f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f32], 
  pP[m12, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15,
    f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, f36, 
   f28, f29, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m13, f1, f3, f4, f6, f7, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f16, f17, 
   f19, f20, f22, f23, f24, f25, f35, f36, f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, 
   f32], pP[m15, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, 
   f13, f14, f15, f16, f16, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, 
   f35, f36, f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m16, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, 
   f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, f28, 
   f29, f31, f33], 
  pP[m17, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, 
   f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f35, f36, f37, f28, f29, 
   f31, f33], 
  pP[m18, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14,
    f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f36, 
   f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m19, f1, f3, f4, f6, f7, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f16, f17, 
   f19, f20, f22, f23, f24, f25, f35, f36, f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, 
   f32], pP[m20, f1, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, 
   f15, f16, f17, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, f36, 
   f37, f28, f29, f38, f31], 
  pP[m21, f1, f2, f4, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15, 
   f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, 
   f28, f29, f31, f33], 
  pP[m23, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, 
   f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, f28, 
   f31, f33], 
  pP[m24, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14,
    f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, 
   f36, f37, f28, f29, f38, f31, f33], 
  pP[m25, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, 
   f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, f28, 
   f29, f31, f33], 
  pP[m26, f1, f2, f4, f5, f7, f8, f9, f10, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, 
   f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f25, f26, f34, f35, f36, f37, 
   f28, f29, f31, f33], 
  pPi[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, 
   f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20, f21, f22, f23, f24, f25, f26, f28, 
   f29, f31, f32, f33, f34, f35, f36, f37, f38, s2]]
graph = Graph[lists, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
maxPairs = 
 FindMaximumFlow[graph, s1, s2, "OptimumFlowData", 
  "EdgeCapacity" -> ConstantArray[1, Length[EdgeList[graph]]]]
maxPairs["FlowGraph"]
DeleteCases[
 DeleteCases[maxPairs["EdgeList"], 
  s1 \[DirectedEdge] _], _ \[DirectedEdge] s2]
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code instead of only pictures.